# C2664: Explicit cast operator do not cast as expected

Tags: c++, explicit

My test class `XString` has two cast operators. But the compiler do not use the explicit cast `operator const wchar_t*()` for `fooA`. Why?

```
class XString
{
public:
    operator const CString&();
    explicit operator const wchar_t*();
};

void fooA(const wchar_t* s);
void fooB(const CString& s);

void test()
{
    XString x;

    CString c = x; //OK

    fooA(x); //Error C2664: 'void fooA(const wchar_t *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'XString' to 'const wchar_t *'

    fooB(x); //OK
}
```

Comment: Because you made it explicit? You need to explicitly cast, with, e.g., `static_cast`.

Comment: The entire point of `explicit` is to disallow implicit conversion.

Comment: x isn't a pointer and fooA expects the address of x or a pointer.

Comment: Note that these are **conversion** operators, not **cast** operators. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `operator const wchar_t*` is `explicit`, the conversion will not be done implicitly. That is the point of `explicit`.

You can force the conversion using `static_cast`:

```
fooA(static_cast<const wchar_t*>(x));
```